# Dart documentation: Use sound parameter types when overriding methods

Tags: dart, documentation

I am reading the Dart documentation on [The Dart type system](https://dart.dev/language/type-system) and quite don't understand the example in the [Use sound return types when overriding methods](https://dart.dev/language/type-system#use-sound-return-types-when-overriding-methods):

This is supposedly correct:

```
class HoneyBadger extends Animal {
  @override
  void chase(Animal a) { ... }

  @override
  HoneyBadger get parent => ...
}
```

but this isn't:

```
class Root extends Animal {
  @override
  void chase(Animal a) { ... }

  @override
  Root get parent => ...
}
```

But the examples are **exactly** the same - they both extends the `Animal` class.  What I am missing?

Comment: Seems like a mistake in the documentation. [File a documentation bug for that page.](https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/new?template=1_page_issue.yml&title=[PAGE%20ISSUE]:%20%27The%20Dart%20type%20system%27&page-url=https://dart.dev/language/type-system.html&page-source=https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/tree/main/src/language/type-system.md)